# Weighted Mean as a Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, calculated-columns, weighted-average

I am trying to add a column with the weighted average of 4 columns with 4 columns of weights

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([('A', [2000, 1000, 2509, 2145]),
                                  ('A_Weight', [37, 47, 33, 16]),
                                  ('B', [2100, 1500, 2000, 1600]),
                                  ('B_weights', [17, 21, 6, 2]),
                                  ('C', [2500, 1400, 0, 2300]),
                                  ('C_weights', [5, 35, 0, 40]),
                                  ('D', [0, 1600, 2100, 2000]),
                                  ('D_weights', [0, 32, 10, 5])]))
```

I want the weighted average to be in a new column named "WA" but every time I try it displays NaN

Desired Dataframe would be a new column with the following values as ex:

Formula I used `(((A * A_weight)+(B * b_weight)+(C * C_weight)+(D * D_weight)) / sum(all weights)`

```
df['WA'] = [2071.19,1323.70, 2363.20,2214.60 ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straight-forward and simple way to do is as follows:

(Since your columns name for the weights are not consistently named, e.g. some with 's' and some without, some with capital 'W' and some with lower case 'w', it is not convenient to group columns e.g. by `.filter()`)

```
df['WA'] = ( (df['A'] * df['A_Weight']) + (df['B'] * df['B_weights']) + (df['C'] * df['C_weights']) + (df['D'] * df['D_weights']) ) / (df['A_Weight'] + df['B_weights'] + df['C_weights'] + df['D_weights'])
```

Result:

```
print(df)


      A  A_Weight     B  B_weights     C  C_weights     D  D_weights           WA
0  2000        37  2100         17  2500          5     0          0  2071.186441
1  1000        47  1500         21  1400         35  1600         32  1323.703704
2  2509        33  2000          6     0          0  2100         10  2363.204082
3  2145        16  1600          2  2300         40  2000          5  2214.603175
```

Answer (score 3):

The not so straight-forward way:

1. Group columns by prefix via [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split)
2. get the column-wise product via [`groupby prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-prod)
3. get the row-wise sum of the products with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum) on axis 1.
4. [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter) + [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum) on axis 1 to get sum of "weights" columns
5. Divide the the group product sums with the weight sums.

```
df['WA'] = (
        df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).prod().sum(axis=1)
        / df.filter(regex='_[wW]eight(s)?$').sum(axis=1)
)
```

```
      A  A_Weight     B  B_weights     C  C_weights     D  D_weights           WA
0  2000        37  2100         17  2500          5     0          0  2071.186441
1  1000        47  1500         21  1400         35  1600         32  1323.703704
2  2509        33  2000          6     0          0  2100         10  2363.204082
3  2145        16  1600          2  2300         40  2000          5  2214.603175
```

Comment: Good use of regex for `.filter()`  +1

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean . I want to be clear that yours should be the accepted answer, I just wanted to see if I could do it this way XD (you already had my +1)

Comment: Yours scale better for a lot of columns.  It's ok no matter who got the accepted answer.  :-)

Comment: Maybe filter with `like=_` for the denominator

Comment: @sammywemmy yeah I went with specific as possible. In this case, assuming no other columns with underscores that certainly works. `regex='_'` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to an old question:

Split data into numerator and denominator:

```py
numerator = df.filter(regex=r"[A-Z]$")
denominator = df.filter(like='_')
```

Convert `denominator` into a MultiIndex, comes in handy when computing with `numerator`:

```py
denominator.columns = denominator.columns.str.split('_', expand = True)
```

Multiply `numerator` by `denominator`, and divide the sum of the outcome with the sum of the `denominator`:

```py
outcome = numerator.mul(denominator, level=0, axis=1).sum(1)
outcome = outcome.div(denominator.sum(1))
df.assign(WA = outcome)

      A  A_Weight     B  B_weights     C  C_weights     D  D_weights           WA
0  2000        37  2100         17  2500          5     0          0  2071.186441
1  1000        47  1500         21  1400         35  1600         32  1323.703704
2  2509        33  2000          6     0          0  2100         10  2363.204082
3  2145        16  1600          2  2300         40  2000          5  2214.603175
```